# Tenho que fazer um formulario em PHP que o custo e o tempo de uma viagem de carro

Tags: php, matemática

Tenho que fazer um formulário em PHP que calcule a distancia, velocidade e tempo que uma pessoa faz durante um percurso e dizer quantos litros foram usado, mas estou com dificuldades para conseguir dar sentido ao formulário.

Calculo

```
    <form action=calculadora.php" method="get" />

        <p> Distancia :      <input name="num1" type="text" /> </p> 
        <p> Tempo :          <input name="num2" type="text" /> </p> 
        <p> Velocidade :  <input name="num3" type="text" />  </p>
        <p> Litros Usados :  <input name="num4" type="text" />  </p>
        <input type="submit" value="Calcular" />     

</form> 
<?php

$num1=$_GET['num1'];
$num2=$_GET['num2'];
$num3=$_GET['num3'];
$num4=$_GET['num4'];

    //Aqui ira o calculo dos valores Num1 Num2 Num3

$d= $num2*$num3; //d= Distancia
$l= $d/12;       //l- Litros Usados



?>      
</body>
```

Comment: Qual o problema ? Pelo visto você está enviando por `GET` para `calculadora.php`, então precisa calcular neste arquivo ou fazer via `JS`,`JQUERY`, etc

Comment: Sua pergunta não faz muito sentido. Você quer calcular "o quê?" se o seu formulário já pede tudo rss

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade está faltando parâmetros. Se você quer saber a quantidade de litros utilizada, você precisa ter uma parâmetro de quantos KM o veículo faz por litro.

Ex:

```
$num1 = 418; //distancia percorrida de 418 km
$consumo_medio = 8; //o consumo do veiculo
$consumo_realizado = $num1 / $consumo_medio; //distancia dividida pelo consumo médio.
```

O valor da variável `$consumo_realizado` será de 52,25 Litros.

Comment: Subentende-de que o consumo foi informado na pergunta nessa linha `$l= $l= $d/12;` sendo 12

Comment: Então vamos lá:
O que falta exatamente? Você quer mostrar na tela o resultado? Quer gravar no banco de dados? Quer mostrar o calculo sem dar refresh na tela? Quer preencher o <input name="num4" type="text" />  com o resultado do calculo?

Pre exemplificar, veja o exemplo https://jsfiddle.net/L4muax9t/25/

Answer (score -1):

Você pode usar a [api do google maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro?hl=pt-br), atraves dela você pode dar o ponto de origem, destino e modo (carro, a pé, ônibus...) e o maps te da distância tempo entre outras várias coisas, também é possível mostrar a rota no html

No caso você  manda os dados via `GET` e o Google retorna um`JSON` com todos os dados, é mais fácil usando JS, mas também é possível usar PHP